# Debugging C# unit test using emacs + netcoredbg

Tags: c#, debugging, emacs

Is it possible to debug C# unit test with emacs?

I'm using lsp and so far only able to debug console application. I cannot make it to work with neither NUnit or XUnit. The debugger won't stop at any of my breakpoints.

FYI:

- Using lsp omnisharp
- Debugging with dap (netcoredbg)

Comment: How are you debugging the unit test? With Debug option ?

Comment: I don't understand debug option that you mentioned. Could you explain?